# is there a way to know why cookie does not get sent to the server

Tags: javascript, node.js, rest, authentication, jwt

please, I am working on a **Nodejs** REST api with sign-up and log-in functionality,

- when a user logs in, they get an accessToken.
- secondly, A cookie is saved containing `refreshToken` to enable the user make request to the `/refresh` endpoint for a new accessToken.

here is my problem; when a user logs in, I can see the cookie, but after subsequent requests to other routes, the cookie **DISAPPEARS** and is no longer sent along to the server, thus preventing me from making a request to the `/refresh` endpoint for a new accessToken.

```js
// log-in controller

const User = require('../model/User');
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt');
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');

const handleLogin = async (req, res) => {
    const { user, pwd } = req.body;
    if (!user || !pwd) return res.status(400).json({ 'message': 'Username and password are required.' });

    const foundUser = await User.findOne({ username: user }).exec();
    if (!foundUser) return res.sendStatus(401); //Unauthorized 
    // evaluate password 
    const match = await bcrypt.compare(pwd, foundUser.password);
    if (match) {
        const roles = Object.values(foundUser.roles).filter(Boolean);
        // create JWTs
        const accessToken = jwt.sign(
            {
                "UserInfo": {
                    "username": foundUser.username,
                    "roles": roles
                }
            },
            process.env.ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET,
            { expiresIn: '10s' }
        );
        const refreshToken = jwt.sign(
            { "username": foundUser.username },
            process.env.REFRESH_TOKEN_SECRET,
            { expiresIn: '1d' }
        );
        // Saving refreshToken with current user
        foundUser.refreshToken = refreshToken;
        const result = await foundUser.save();
        console.log(result);
        console.log(roles);

        // Creates Secure Cookie with refresh token
        res.cookie('jwt', refreshToken, { httpOnly: true, secure: true, sameSite: 'None', maxAge: 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000 });

        // Send authorization roles and access token to user
        res.json({ roles, accessToken });

    } else {
        res.sendStatus(401);
    }
}

module.exports = { handleLogin };
```

```js
// refresh endpoint controller

const User = require('../model/User');
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');

const handleRefreshToken = async (req, res) => {
    const cookies = req.cookies;
    if (!cookies?.jwt) return res.sendStatus(401);
    const refreshToken = cookies.jwt;

    const foundUser = await User.findOne({ refreshToken }).exec();
    if (!foundUser) return res.sendStatus(403); //Forbidden 
    // evaluate jwt 
    jwt.verify(
        refreshToken,
        process.env.REFRESH_TOKEN_SECRET,
        (err, decoded) => {
            if (err || foundUser.username !== decoded.username) return res.sendStatus(403);
            const roles = Object.values(foundUser.roles);
            const accessToken = jwt.sign(
                {
                    "UserInfo": {
                        "username": decoded.username,
                        "roles": roles
                    }
                },
                process.env.ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET,
                { expiresIn: '10s' }
            );
            res.json({ roles, accessToken })
        }
    );
}

module.exports = { handleRefreshToken }
```

Comment: This sound like the cookie expires.

Comment: the cookie can't expire it is set to one day.

Comment: Open the network tab in the dev tools and check the requests and responses. There has to be a last request containing the cookie and a first request without the cookie. There you should find a response that modifies or deletes the cookie.

Comment: I have to mention that I am using thunder client to test the API, and when I check the cookies tab, it shows "No Cookies Available"

Comment: In the question you wrote: _when a user logs in, I can see the cookie_. In your comment you wrote: _when I check the cookies tab, it shows "No Cookies Available"_

Comment: Refresh tokens do not belong in cookies! Why even bother with a separate refresh/access token at this point? https://evertpot.com/jwt-is-a-bad-default/ . Why isn't this OAuth2? Don't roll your own

Answer (score 0):

I ran into same issue as you had: thunder client could not send cookie back in sub sequential request. I fixed this issue after changing `res.cookie` in `handleLogin`. Give it a try:

```
res.cookie('jwt', refreshToken, { httpOnly: true, maxAge: 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check if you are using cookies parser middleware at right place in your server.js

Comment: Instead of simply providing the answer directly, try writing a detailed comment that explains the solution, as long as the explanation is not too lengthy.

Answer (score -2):

The JWT refresh token is a one-off thing.
So, in your code after user signs in in the JWT server, you are getting accessToken which expires in 10 seconds, and refresh token which you are saving into the user's browser cookies. After accessToken expires, you are generating new accessToken using user's refreshToken. At this moment your current refreshToken becomes outdated, and when you will try to generate one more accessToken (in 10 seconds), it will fail.
So, in the handleRefreshToken() function you need to generate brand new refreshToken:

```
        const refreshToken = jwt.sign(
            { "username": foundUser.username },
            process.env.REFRESH_TOKEN_SECRET,
            { expiresIn: '1d' }
        );
        // Saving refreshToken with current user
        foundUser.refreshToken = refreshToken;
        const result = await foundUser.save();
        console.log(result);
        console.log(roles);

        // Creates Secure Cookie with refresh token
        res.cookie('jwt', refreshToken, { httpOnly: true, secure: true, sameSite: 'None', maxAge: 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000 });
```

Comment: I don't understand how the browser cookie is deleted in the author's code, but anyway, refreshToken is invalidated on server side. So, even if it's still in user's browser, it doesn't matter

Comment: I have to mention that I am using thunder client to test the API, and when I check the cookies tab, it shows "No Cookies Available".